# How to save a GoogleMap polly line in SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, google-maps

I've got a specific problem. I'm creating an application which has to save and then get a particullar locatons form database and recreate a polly line on a GoogleMap. Which tools, libraries or techniques schould I use to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `PolyUtils` methods from the [Google Maps API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/):

- The `PolyUtils.encode` method encodes a `List<LatLng>` into a `String` that you can store in your database.
- The `PolyUtils.decode` method decodes a `String` into a `List<LatLng>` that you can manage with your map.

**Update from the comments:**

You will need to add a dependency (from [the documentation](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/)):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}
```

Comment: Could you give more information about this method?
I mean, do i have to import external library?